# If $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, will $ \lim_{r\to\infty} \int_{\partial B_n(0,r)} |f|^2 dS$ also be finite?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

If a function $f$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, will
$$
\lim_{r\to\infty} \int_{\partial B_n(0,r)} |f|^2 dS
$$
also be finite?

If so, can this be generalized to any $L^p$ space? If not, what are some counter-examples?

Comment: You should have $\|f\|_2^2 =\int_0^\infty \int_{\partial B_n(0,r)}|f|^2 d S dr$. This should allow you to find a counterexample.